# How to use custom lookup in data table in lightning?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-experience

[image]I want to use lookup in the data table when I used type:'lookup' but it's not showing over there.
{ label:'PN QuoTed', fieldName:'Part__c.Name',type:'lookup', sortable : true, editable : 'true' },
I also used a custom lookup component over there in my code.
Any alternate method to use custom lookup in the Data-table in lightning.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend reviewing the following article:  [10 Tips for Implementing an Efficient Lightning Lookup](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/2018/07/10-tips-for-implementing-an-efficient-lightning-lookup-component.html).  At the end the author provides a link to his Git repo for access to working code.

Good luck :)

Comment: Rahul indora did you manage to find solution? I am having the same issue